# Why is POSIX's libgen.h called like that?

Tags: c, unix, posix

POSIX contains a header called libgen.h (not very explicit by itself), described as

> definitions for pattern matching functions

And contains the following function definitions:

```
char  *basename(char *);
char  *dirname(char *);
```

It used to contain two Regex-related functions, but they were removed in Issue 6.

Which leads me to the question: why "libgen"?

Comment: Hysterical raisens.

Comment: (he means historical reasons. Probably it had some meaning in some version of UNIX, then everyone started using it so POSIX had to write it down the way it was)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `<libgen.h>` is probably some variant of 'general library' — but history doesn't really relate.

In my printed copy of the AT&T Unix SVR4 Programmer's Reference Manual (published by Prentice-Hall in 1990 with ISBN 0-13-947029-8, but Google doesn't know much about that ISBN), there were many other functions defined in the `<libgen.h>` header.  Section 3G "General Purpose Library Routines" listed `basename()` and `dirname()` and these other functions:

- `bgets()` (similar to modern `getdelim()`)
- `bufsplit()`
- `copylist()`
- `gmatch()` (similar to modern `fnmatch()`)
- `isencrypt()`
- `mkdirp()` (create directories in a path name)
- `rmdirp()` (remove directories in a path name)
- `p2open()` and `p2close()` (bi-directional communication with a sub-process — related to `popen()` and `pclose()`)
- `pathfind()`
- `regcmp()` and `regex()` (regular expressions)
- `strfind()`, `strrspn()`, `strtrns()`
- `strccpy()`, `strcadd()`, `strecpy()`, `streadd()`

You needed to link the program with `-lgen` (`libgen.a`, `libgen.so`) to gain access to these functions.

Comment: Section 3G is called "General Purpose Library routines" so you are very likely correct. SVR4 is from 1989 though. There is an archived version [here](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_attunixSystemVRelease4ProgrammersReferenceManual19_55505648) for the history buffs.

Comment: For some reason, the copyright years are listed in reverse order ("Copyright 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987, 1986, 1985, 1984, 1983 AT&T", for example.  I've never seen that before.  Anyway, I'll update the date — thanks, @EmanuelP.